# Precalculus - Where is this (trig) function positive and negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to know how where this function is positive and negative over the interval $[0, 8]$.

$f(x) = 2(\tan x)(\cos x) - 4(\sin x)^2$

I solved for values of x and I got $0, \pi, 2\pi, \pi/6, 5\pi/6$, and $13\pi/6$. Also, the function doesn't exist at $\pi/2, 3\pi/2$, and $5\pi/2$, because of the $\tan x$. Now, how can I find where the function is positive and negative (without the use of a calculator, obviously)?

I could just plug in numbers in each of the intervals, but I don't think that is what the intended way to do it is.

Comment: Try to simplify $f(x)$ by using identity $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Comment: I did, thats how I solved for the critical values, and now that I have them, I want to figure out how I can get where it is positive and negative without having to plug in numbers in between each critical value.

Comment: After you simplify $f(x)$, you can let $2\sin(x) =u$. Solve $u(1-u)>0$ like a normal quadratic inequality.

Comment: As Nicholas stated if you write $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, then the problem is much simpler. After the substitution, try to find the where $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @OFRBG I don't know if I'm missing something but I think just said twice that (once in the question and onces in the comments) that I did solve for where f(x) is 0.

Comment: @Nicholas So that would get me where 2sin(x) is positive, so now how do I know where x is positive?

Comment: @4everPixelated That will not let you know where $2\sin(x)$ is positive, it lets you know for what values of $2\sin(x)$ and thus $x$ causes $f(x)$ to be positive where $f(x) = u(1-u)$.

Comment: @Nicholas Oh yeah, you're right, but still, how do I know where x is positive?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your question wants you to find the values of $x$ where $f(x)$ is positive. If you plot a graph of $y=f(x)$, it makes no sense to ask where $x$ is positive because $x$ is positive past the $y-axis$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = 2(\tan x)(\cos x) - 4(\sin x)^2$

$f(x) = 2\sin x - 4(\sin x)^2$

$f(x) = 2\sin x (1 - 2\sin x)$

You can imagine $f(x)=u(1-u)$, a quadratic curve that intersects the $y-axis$ at $u=0$ and $u=1$ and stationary point above the $y-axis$.

For $f(x)>0$, $$0<2\sin x<1$$

$$ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{6} $$

I will leave you to find the other ranges of $x$ in the interval.